# element with border-radius and overflow hidden can't clip contents with position absolute which it is not the element's direct child

Tags: html, css, layout, overflow

In Chrome 60.0.3112.90(64-bit).
My system is macOS 10.12.4
[image]

As you can see, the blue box is overflow. How can I solve this problem? And why does it overflow?

Please check this [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/1w8rsz42/6/)

or this is my code.

```css
.outer {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.inner {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: scroll;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.inner2 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: lightgray;
}

.inner3 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
    <div class="inner2">
      <div class="inner3"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: it's working fine in the jsfiddle provided.

Comment: sorry! I should mention that the problem appears in chrome 60.

Comment: Its working fine in chrome 60

Comment: I can reproduce the issue on Chrome `Version 60.0.3112.90 (Official Build) (64-bit)` - `Mac 10.12.6.` Please stop flagging the question.

Comment: My version is `60.0.3112.90(64-bit)`, My system is macOS 10.12.4. Is this a BUG or something...

Comment: @zhuscat, I agree with *moonflare*, I also can't reproduce this issue. My Chrome is `version 60.0.3112.90 (64-bit)` and I am using `Mac 10.12.6`.

Comment: Does [this](https://jsfiddle.net/1w8rsz42/7/) help you?

Comment: @JithinRajPR Weird. In Chrome 62.0.3184.0 Canary, I still have this problem. But in Safari, the problem disappears.

Comment: @Huelfe Yes, why.

Comment: it is a positioning problem. i gave first div `z-index: 1` and the other divs `z-index: 0`.

Comment: @Huelfe No. I find that if I give the first z-index property, no matter what value it is, the problem can be solved.

Comment: And `transform: translate(0, 0);` also works. Maybe it is related to stacking context. I'm not an expert at it.

Comment: It occurs on Chrome version 114.0.5735.133.

Answer (score 2):

You can apply `z-index: 1` to `.outer` CSS class.
You can also try [this](https://gist.github.com/adamcbrewer/5859738) solution, it's used a lot by other guys.

You have [here](https://jsfiddle.net/moonflare/1w8rsz42/10/) a working demo

Comment: I find that any thing that can create a stacking context can solve this problem.